# Неявное приведение типов в Java

Tags: java, типы, конвертация

Учу Java, читаю Шилдта. Уже много раз прочитал, что Java — сильно типизированный язык. Почему следующий код выкидывает ошибку

```
int i = 10;
i = i / 2.5;
```

А такой код прекрасно работает и присваивает к `i` значение `4`?

```
int i = 10;
i /= 2.5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так работает оператор присваивания, если переменная типа `int`, а `i / 2.5` типа `double`, то вы не можете присвоить значение типа `double` к типу `int` без явного каста.

То есть проверка типов осуществляется перед *присваиванием* переменной значения. Во втором случае утверждение является *выражением*, в котором значение преобразовывается к типу *операнда*, то есть чтобы можно было осуществить операцию и обратно к типу переменной, где должно хранится значение. То есть

```
int i = 10;
d = i /= 2.5;
```

тоже будет работать, поскольку нначения `int` преобразовавыются к `double` перед присваиванием *без* потери точности, обратное не верно и вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Не противоречит ли такое автоматическое приведение double к int концепции сильной типизации?

Comment: Тип переменной при компиляции не меняется, во время выполнения тип переменной может меняться, тем не менее вы не можете изменить тип без каста если этот тип не поддерживает конвертацию типов по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3):

операция типа

```
i /= 2.5;
```

это операция с автоматическим приведением типов, будет записана как

```
i = (int) i/2.5;
```

тоже самое с

```
double d = 1d;
int i = 1;
i = i * d; // ошибка
i *= d; // нет ошибки
```

с операциями инкрементации и декрементации анологичная ситуация.