# int + '\n' - что происходит при таком условии?

Tags: java, циклы, for

При изучении в Java цикла `for` написала простой цикл, который должен выводить все четные числа до 100 и оставлять между ними строку. Я нашла в итоге ответ, что надо было ставить двойные кавычки, вместо одинарных и то, что я задумала, у меня в итоге получилось. Но я так и не поняла, что происходит в этом случае:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i=i+2)
            System.out.println(i+'\n');
```

Я прочитала, что тут происходит конкатенация, но совершенно не могу понять что с чем, если в ответе:

```
12  
14  
16  
18  
20
```

etc
Почему возвращаются цифры с 12?

Comment: потому что `\n` обозначает символ с кодом 10. 10+2=12

Comment: Конкатенация — это у строк, но у вас здесь нет ни одной строки и поэтому происходит обычное сложение чисел

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Двойные кавычки

Строковые литералы (константы типа `String`) заключаются в двойные кавычки:

```
String s = "a"; //это строка
```

Оператор `+` в котором участвует строка и другой объект/примитивное значение приводят к конкатенации:

```
String newString = 1+"a"; //1a
```

### Одинарные кавычки

Символьные литералы (константы типа `char`) заключаются в одинарные кавычки:

```
char ch = 'a';
```

Тип `char`, в отличие от `String` — целочисленный тип ([JLS §4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)) это означает, что каждый символ представляет собой числовое значение символа в кодировке UTF-16. Как следствие, `char` можно привести к числу:

```
System.out.println((int) 'a');  //97
System.out.println((int) '\n'); //10
```

Оператор `+` для `char` также работает по-другому, при сложении (`i+'\n'`) конкатенации не происходит, просто прибавляется числовое значение символа `\n`, а именно 10

### Оператор +

Поведение оператора `+` описывается в спецификации Java ([§15.18 Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)):

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> *Если один из операндов имеет тип `String`, то операция представляет собой конкатенацию строк.
>
> В противном случае тип каждого операнда оператора + должен быть преобразуемым (§5.1.8) в примитивный числовой тип, иначе генерируется ошибка времени компиляции.*

Comment: Хорошо затмил мой ответ, но я все равно не понял к какому типу относится операция + в данном случае?

Comment: @RomanC Операции в Java вроде как к типам не относятся. Добавил ссылку на поведение оператора в спецификации. Стало лучше?

Comment: А к чему они относятся как не к типам )), java - это строго типизированный язык, но есть некоторые исключения о которых я упомянул ссылкой в моём ответе.

Comment: @RomanC Ну, в некоторых языках операторы могут быть переопределены для определенных типов. В Java их поведение «зашито» в спецификацию языка. Поэтому не совсем понятен вопрос «к какому типу относится операция + ». Имелось ввиду какой тип возвращается? К какому типу приводятся операнды?

Comment: Нет такого не может быть никогда в Java. В C++, да, но это другой язык.

Answer (score 2):

При выполнении операции сложения оба операнда должны быть `int`, и результат тоже получается `int`, после его получения значение преобразуется в `String` (здесь ссылка на [print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-int-)),  потом печатается на экран.

Операция конкатенации выполняется если один из операндов имеет тип `String`.

Вот здесь правильный перевод документации [JLS-15.18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)(спасибо Гугл):

> Если тип любого из операндов оператора + - String, то операция - конкатенация строк.
>
> В противном случае тип каждого из операндов оператора + должен быть типом, который *можно* преобразовать ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) в примитивный числовой тип, иначе произойдет ошибка времени компиляции.

Comment: И вот для того, чтобы отличить это явное преобразование от неявного, советую почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882085/204920

Comment: Оба операнда не должны быть `int` (один из них `char`). И оборачиваться в `Integer` значение в данном случае не будет, т.к. [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-) перегружен. Перевод хорош, да, но выделенная часть про boxing, которого здесь нет.

Comment: Integer это уже будет результат бохинга, но запомни, что сложение это операция над числами, а не символами.

Comment: Так боксинга в примере из вопроса не будет, поэтому странно на нем так заострять внимание. В контексте Java символы — числовой тип.

Comment: Там ссылка на анбохинг, это уже другое. Перегрузка метода действительно есть, но вопрос с бохингом остаётся открытый.

Comment: Там где нет боксинга и анбоксинга не будет :)

Comment: Пустые слова без подтверждения не нужно комментировать. Возможно я был прав изначально и зря отредактировал свой вопрос потому, что метод работает аналогично Integer.toString

Comment: Да нет, после исправлений ответ стал лучше. На практике [`Integer.toString`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l397) экономит на создании нового объекта `Integer` и работает с примитивом. Но это деталь реализации, суть в том что оборачивание не гарантируется.

Comment: Ну это уже проблемы перегрузчика и его приоритетов, наверное это можно исправить, но скорее порождает новую проблему вместо существующей.